# Test '-timeout 0' not reflected in execution

Tags: testing, go

I am using Go **1.9.2** version and invoking the test with timeout disabled using `-timeout 0` flag.

`go test my_module -run TestModule -v --race -timeout 0`

But the test execution is getting timed out after default timeout of 10m.

> *** Test killed: ran too long (10m0s).

Answer (score 0):

It's `test.timeout` i.e.

`go test my_module -run TestModule -v --race -test.timeout 0`

Answer (score -1):

Its the way the `testing` library is handling that flag value:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/adcecbe05ef812bc8ff477dec47720a2cfc273e3/src/testing/testing.go#L1299

It only uses the given value if the `timeout` is greater than `0`. Therefore, by setting it to 0, it just uses the default (`10m`).

Comment: But the code is anyway going to set it to `Zero (0)` as per the line `https://github.com/golang/go/blob/adcecbe05ef812bc8ff477dec47720a2cfc273e3/src/testing/testing.go#L271`. So passing the same value as part of external params will be behaving the same I guess

Comment: Right, if you had done `-timeout 1`, it would be set to `1` instead and be a very quick timeout.

Comment: So it doesn't solve the problem I have mentioned. How to get that working in this version ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Why do you want to have the test immediately timeout?

Comment: All I want is to disable timeout for my go test. But currently if I use `-timeout 0`, the test still timesout after the default time of `10m`

Comment: You could go the other way and do something like `100h`, which would feel like turning it off.